# Converting a list to csv file using R

Tags: r, csv, parsing

I have a list in the form

```
0 -121.904167 41.974556
1 -121.902153 41.974766
2 -121.896790 41.988075
....
```

and I need to convert it to a csv file  in the form (using R)

```
0; -121.904167; 41.974556
1; -121.902153; 41.974766
2; -121.896790; 41.988075
```

I import list

```
doc1 <- readLines("https://www.cs.utah.edu/~lifeifei/research/tpq/cal.cnode")
```

then I am replacing white spaces with semicolons

```
doc1 <- gsub("\\s+",";", doc1)
```

and then I export `doc1` into a .csv file

```
cat(doc1, file = "doc1.csv")
```

but my exported file looks a bit messed up. To start with, all lines are one next to the other and not one under the other.
Furthermore, the last element of my first line is considered to be attached to the first element of second line etc

To let you know what exactly I mean if I import this .csv file to an Excel (this is not my ultimate goal here, just for the sake of clarification)
I get all my file write into a single row, where columns are

```
0 | -121.904167 | 41.974556 1 | -121.902153 | 41.974766 2 | -121.896790 .....
```

while my csv file opened in sublime looks like this

```
0;-121.904167;41.974556 1;-121.902153;41.974766 2;-121.896790;41.988075 3;-121.889603;41.998032 4;-121.886681;42.008739 5;-121.915062;41.970314 6;-121.910088;41.973942 7;-121.916199;41.969482
```

any idea how to correctly implement that using R?

Comment: why don't you use the `?write.table` family of functions?

Comment: @docendodiscimus problem does not lie with writing csv file, rather than parsing it and adding semicolons while keeping line order.

Comment: well to me it looks like you should read the data using the `read.table` family of functions so you get a `data.frame` and then there's no need for parsing or manually insertng semicolons because that's what the `write.table` family of function does for you.

Comment: You have a problem reading the data.  Look more closely at the first doc1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
input<-fread(input = "https://www.cs.utah.edu/~lifeifei/research/tpq/cal.cnode")
```

Check that it was imported OK.

```
 >dim(input)
 [1] 21048     3
```

Finally export it as csv with comma delimiter (by default):

```
 write.csv(input,"output.csv",row.names = F)
```

Comment: Why do you need `fread`? You can simply use base R `write.csv2(read.table("https://www.cs.utah.edu/~lifeifei/research/tpq/cal.cnode"), file = "myfile.csv")`

Comment: I prefer it. Faster more reliable. Base works ok as well, it's a matter of taste I guess

Comment: in both cases `col.names = F` does not work, it creates csv file adding `"V1";"V2";"V3"` in top row. I get the following error: Warning message:
In write.csv(input, file = "output.csv", row.names = F, col.names = F) :
  attempt to set 'col.names' ignored

Comment: @TomZinger there is no argument such as `col.names` neither in `write.csv` nor in `write.csv2`. In the console try `?write.csv` If you need to add column names try names(input)<-c("a","b","c")  _before_ you save as a .csv

Comment: @amonk you are right. I used help for write.csv but for some reason, it returns instructions for write.table, hence `write.table(input, file = "output.csv", col.names = F, row.names = F, sep = ";")` does the job.

Comment: in this file https://www.cs.utah.edu/~lifeifei/research/tpq/CA it fails though, possibly because there are several lines where you have only 1 string instead of three.

Comment: @TomZinger what exactly fails? send the error log as well

Comment: `doc3<-fread(input = "https://www.cs.utah.edu/~lifeifei/research/tpq/CA")` returns: Error in fread(input = "https://www.cs.utah.edu/~lifeifei/research/tpq/CA") : 
  Expected sep (' ') but new line, EOF (or other non printing character) ends field 0 when detecting types from point 5: pillar

Comment: @TomZinger Line 52706 contains only the string `pillar` and no numeric data. So you need to QA it first (by downloading it of course)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147718/discussion-between-amonk-and-tom-zinger).